# How to use ensurevisible method in listview?

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have a `ListView` *contains 100 items*, and we can do certain activities based on selected items. I have used `EnsureVisible()` method to adjust the visibility and my `ListView` refreshing time to time to update the data.

The problem now i am facing is if I select the first item in the list, I then start paging down *(maybe select the 21th, 59th
and 75th)* during this select, I could have highlighted the 1st, 24th and
56th when the control suddenly refreshes the page in this instance, only the 1st selected retains the focus and I have lost my other selections and have to go through again either individually or just quicker.

So my question is how i can select multiple items and do the action while `ListView` is refreshing during certain interval to fill data though `EnsureVisible()` is used?

This is my exisitng code:

```
 if (_listviewFirst.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            _listviewFirst.SelectedItems[_listviewFirst.SelectedItems.Count - 1].EnsureVisible();
            _listviewFirst.SelectedItems[0].EnsureVisible();
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you should save a List of Items key-values somewhere after each selected Item. then after refresh re-select that list

Comment: @Boomer can i use ListView.TopItem property in these scenario, i dont know whether it will work, if then how can i use

Comment: Why does your control suddenly refresh? You could try using checkboxes instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes.aspx

Comment: @Tony Day refresh in the sence it is filling data on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `ListView.ItemSelectionChanged` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged.aspx)) event and add/remove items (or their references) from a `List` of selected items. When your control is refreshed you should then iterate your selected items and update the items to selected in your `ListView`.

You will be able to take advantage of `e.IsSelected` and `e.Item` or `e.ItemIndex` in the event handler to do this.

I wouldn't use `EnsureVisible` at all for this.